# Problem with $\log(\exp(z)) \neq z$ and solving equations

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms, problem-solving, inverse-function

In the real numbers, we always have that $\log(\exp(x)) = x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. However, as [How to prove $\log(\exp(z))\neq z$ if $z\in \mathbb{C}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2705482/how-to-prove-log-expz-neq-z-if-z-in-mathbbc) shows, we can find some $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\log(\exp(z))\neq z$ depending on the branch of $\log$ that we use. So if I have an equation $f(z) = \exp(g(z))$, and I want to isolate $g(z)$, I would just take logarithms and be done if I were working in $\mathbb{R}$. But if I am working in $\mathbb{C}$, I can't be assured that $\log(\exp(g(z)) = g(z)$, so how could I accomplish isolating $g(z)$? I assume that I would have to choose a specific branch cut to accomplish this but am not certain which one to choose.

**NOTE**: Assume that I have no prior knowledge of what values $f(z)$ takes on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\log f(z) = \log |f(z)| + i \arg f(z)$$

$$\log |f(z)| = \log \exp( \Re(g(z))) = \Re(g(z)).$$

$$\arg f(z) = \arg \exp(g(z)) = \arg \exp(i \Im g(z)).$$

Yes, you'll need to define your branch to compute the argument, and then

$$ \log f(z) = \Re(g(z)) + i \arg \exp(i \Im g(z)).$$

$$ \log f(z) = \Re(g(z)) + i  (\Im g(z)+ 2k\pi )\quad (k \text{ depends on the branch}).$$

For the example you allude to:

$$g(z) = z = x+ i y,$$
$$\log f(z)  = x + i \arg \exp( i y) = x + i (y + 2k\pi), \quad (k \text{ depends on the branch}).$$

Comment: So is is true that $\log(\exp(g(z))) = g(z)$ for all $g\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ if I set $k=0$? And if so, how do we define the branch to force $k=0$?

Comment: You would need to restrict $y$, so that $z$ lies in a strip:  for example $\alpha \le   y < \alpha + 2\pi,$ with $\alpha \in \text{ Reals}.$  Then define your branch with the argument of the logarithm having the same constraints.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, if $\Re(g(z)) \in [\alpha, \alpha+2\pi)$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, then there exists a branch of $\log$ such that $\log(\exp(g(z))) = g(z)$, but otherwise the best we can do is to conclude that $\log(\exp(g(z))) = g(z) + 2k\pi i$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ for any branch of $\log$?

Comment: I think that's right (with $\Im(g(z)) \in [\alpha,\alpha+2\pi)$).

Comment: Yes, I should have put $\Im(g(z))$ instead of $\Re(g(z))$. Thanks for catching that mistake!

Comment: You are welcome.